# Issue with python netapp Lib: "the python NetApp-Lib module is required"

Tags: python, ansible

I'm creating a volume on the  netapp Cdot Storage by Ansible, there is netapps cdot module is available for Ansible which is written in Python. One piece of the code is below. Now when I'm  using this module to create my netapp vol as given in example below, it's throwing an issue `"the python NetApp-Lib module is required"`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# (c) 2017, NetApp, Inc
#
# This file is part of Ansible
#
# Ansible is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# Ansible is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with Ansible.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
#
ANSIBLE_METADATA = {'metadata_version': '1.0',
                    'status': ['preview'],
                    'supported_by': 'community'}


DOCUMENTATION = '''

module: na_cdot_volume

short_description: Manage NetApp cDOT volumes
extends_documentation_fragment:
    - netapp.ontap
version_added: '2.3'
author: Sumit Kumar (sumit4@netapp.com)

description:
- Create or destroy volumes on NetApp cDOT

options:

  state:
    description:
    - Whether the specified volume should exist or not.
    required: true
    choices: ['present', 'absent']

  name:
    description:
    - The name of the lun to manage.
    required: true

  infinite:
    description:
    - Set True if the volume is an Infinite Volume.
    choices: ['True', 'False']
    default: 'False'

  online:
    description:
    - Whether the specified volume is online, or not.
    choices: ['True', 'False']
    default: 'True'

  aggregate_name:
    description:
    - The name of the aggregate the flexvol should exist on. Required when C(state=present).

  size:
    description:
    - The size of the volume in (size_unit). Required when C(state=present).

  size_unit:
    description:
    - The unit used to interpret the size parameter.
    choices: ['bytes', 'b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb', 'pb', 'eb', 'zb', 'yb']
    default: 'gb'

  vserver:
    description:
    - Name of the vserver to use.
    required: true
    default: None

'''

EXAMPLES = """

    - name: Create FlexVol
      na_cdot_volume:
        state: present
        name: ansibleVolume
        infinite: False
        aggregate_name: aggr1
        size: 20
        size_unit: mb
        vserver: ansibleVServer
        hostname: "{{ netapp_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ netapp_username }}"
        password: "{{ netapp_password }}"

    - name: Make FlexVol offline
      na_cdot_volume:
        state: present
        name: ansibleVolume
        infinite: False
        online: False
        vserver: ansibleVServer
        hostname: "{{ netapp_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ netapp_username }}"
        password: "{{ netapp_password }}"

"""

RETURN = """


"""

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible.module_utils.pycompat24 import get_exception
import ansible.module_utils.netapp as netapp_utils

HAS_NETAPP_LIB = netapp_utils.has_netapp_lib()


class NetAppCDOTVolume(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self._size_unit_map = dict(
            bytes=1,
            b=1,
            kb=1024,
            mb=1024 ** 2,
            gb=1024 ** 3,
            tb=1024 ** 4,
            pb=1024 ** 5,
            eb=1024 ** 6,
            zb=1024 ** 7,
            yb=1024 ** 8
        )

        self.argument_spec = netapp_utils.ontap_sf_host_argument_spec()
        self.argument_spec.update(dict(
            state=dict(required=True, choices=['present', 'absent']),
            name=dict(required=True, type='str'),
            is_infinite=dict(required=False, type='bool', default=False, aliases=['infinite']),
            is_online=dict(required=False, type='bool', default=True, aliases=['online']),
            size=dict(type='int'),
            size_unit=dict(default='gb',
                           choices=['bytes', 'b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb',
                                    'pb', 'eb', 'zb', 'yb'], type='str'),
            aggregate_name=dict(type='str'),
            vserver=dict(required=True, type='str', default=None),
        ))

        self.module = AnsibleModule(
            argument_spec=self.argument_spec,
            required_if=[
                ('state', 'present', ['aggregate_name', 'size'])
            ],
            supports_check_mode=True
        )

        p = self.module.params

        # set up state variables
        self.state = p['state']
        self.name = p['name']
        self.is_infinite = p['is_infinite']
        self.is_online = p['is_online']
        self.size_unit = p['size_unit']
        self.vserver = p['vserver']

        if p['size'] is not None:
            self.size = p['size'] * self._size_unit_map[self.size_unit]
        else:
            self.size = None
        self.aggregate_name = p['aggregate_name']

        if HAS_NETAPP_LIB is False:
            self.module.fail_json(msg="the python NetApp-Lib module is required")
        else:
            self.server = netapp_utils.setup_ontap_zapi(module=self.module, vserver=self.vserver)

    def get_volume(self):
        """
        Return details about the volume
        :param:
            name : Name of the volume

        :return: Details about the volume. None if not found.
        :rtype: dict
        """
        volume_info = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement('volume-get-iter')
        volume_attributes = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement('volume-attributes')
        volume_id_attributes = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement('volume-id-attributes')
        volume_id_attributes.add_new_child('name', self.name)
        volume_attributes.add_child_elem(volume_id_attributes)

        query = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement('query')
        query.add_child_elem(volume_attributes)

        volume_info.add_child_elem(query)

        result = self.server.invoke_successfully(volume_info, True)

        return_value = None

        if result.get_child_by_name('num-records') and \
                int(result.get_child_content('num-records')) >= 1:

            volume_attributes = result.get_child_by_name(
                'attributes-list').get_child_by_name(
                'volume-attributes')
            # Get volume's current size
            volume_space_attributes = volume_attributes.get_child_by_name(
                'volume-space-attributes')
            current_size = volume_space_attributes.get_child_content('size')

            # Get volume's state (online/offline)
            volume_state_attributes = volume_attributes.get_child_by_name(
                'volume-state-attributes')
            current_state = volume_state_attributes.get_child_content('state')
            is_online = None
            if current_state == "online":
                is_online = True
            elif current_state == "offline":
                is_online = False
            return_value = {
                'name': self.name,
                'size': current_size,
                'is_online': is_online,
            }

        return return_value

    def create_volume(self):
        volume_create = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
            'volume-create', **{'volume': self.name,
                                'containing-aggr-name': self.aggregate_name,
                                'size': str(self.size)})

        try:
            self.server.invoke_successfully(volume_create,
                                            enable_tunneling=True)
        except netapp_utils.zapi.NaApiError:
            err = get_exception()
            self.module.fail_json(msg='Error provisioning volume %s of size %s' % (self.name, self.size),
                                  exception=str(err))

    def delete_volume(self):
        if self.is_infinite:
            volume_delete = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                'volume-destroy-async', **{'volume-name': self.name})
        else:
            volume_delete = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                'volume-destroy', **{'name': self.name, 'unmount-and-offline':
                    'true'})

        try:
            self.server.invoke_successfully(volume_delete,
                                            enable_tunneling=True)
        except netapp_utils.zapi.NaApiError:
            err = get_exception()
            self.module.fail_json(msg='Error deleting volume %s' % self.name,
                                  exception=str(err))

    def rename_volume(self):
        """
        Rename the volume.

        Note: 'is_infinite' needs to be set to True in order to rename an
        Infinite Volume.
        """
        if self.is_infinite:
            volume_rename = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                'volume-rename-async',
                **{'volume-name': self.name, 'new-volume-name': str(
                    self.name)})
        else:
            volume_rename = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                'volume-rename', **{'volume': self.name, 'new-volume-name': str(
                    self.name)})
        try:
            self.server.invoke_successfully(volume_rename,
                                            enable_tunneling=True)
        except netapp_utils.zapi.NaApiError:
            err = get_exception()
            self.module.fail_json(msg='Error renaming volume %s' % self.name,
                                  exception=str(err))

    def resize_volume(self):
        """
        Re-size the volume.

        Note: 'is_infinite' needs to be set to True in order to rename an
        Infinite Volume.
        """
        if self.is_infinite:
            volume_resize = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                'volume-size-async',
                **{'volume-name': self.name, 'new-size': str(
                    self.size)})
        else:
            volume_resize = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                'volume-size', **{'volume': self.name, 'new-size': str(
                    self.size)})
        try:
            self.server.invoke_successfully(volume_resize,
                                            enable_tunneling=True)
        except netapp_utils.zapi.NaApiError:
            err = get_exception()
            self.module.fail_json(msg='Error re-sizing volume %s' % self.name,
                                  exception=str(err))

    def change_volume_state(self):
        """
        Change volume's state (offline/online).

        Note: 'is_infinite' needs to be set to True in order to change the
        state of an Infinite Volume.
        """
        state_requested = None
        if self.is_online:
            # Requested state is 'online'.
            state_requested = "online"
            if self.is_infinite:
                volume_change_state = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                    'volume-online-async',
                    **{'volume-name': self.name})
            else:
                volume_change_state = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                    'volume-online',
                    **{'name': self.name})
        else:
            # Requested state is 'offline'.
            state_requested = "offline"
            if self.is_infinite:
                volume_change_state = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                    'volume-offline-async',
                    **{'volume-name': self.name})
            else:
                volume_change_state = netapp_utils.zapi.NaElement.create_node_with_children(
                    'volume-offline',
                    **{'name': self.name})
        try:
            self.server.invoke_successfully(volume_change_state,
                                            enable_tunneling=True)
        except netapp_utils.zapi.NaApiError:
            err = get_exception()
            self.module.fail_json(msg='Error changing the state of volume %s to %s' % (self.name, state_requested),
                                  exception=str(err))

    def apply(self):
        changed = False
        volume_exists = False
        rename_volume = False
        resize_volume = False
        volume_detail = self.get_volume()

        if volume_detail:
            volume_exists = True

            if self.state == 'absent':
                changed = True

            elif self.state == 'present':
                if str(volume_detail['size']) != str(self.size):
                    resize_volume = True
                    changed = True
                if (volume_detail['is_online'] is not None) and (volume_detail['is_online'] != self.is_online):
                    changed = True
                    if self.is_online is False:
                        # Volume is online, but requested state is offline
                        pass
                    else:
                        # Volume is offline but requested state is online
                        pass

        else:
            if self.state == 'present':
                changed = True

        if changed:
            if self.module.check_mode:
                pass
            else:
                if self.state == 'present':
                    if not volume_exists:
                        self.create_volume()

                    else:
                        if resize_volume:
                            self.resize_volume()
                        if volume_detail['is_online'] is not \
                                None and volume_detail['is_online'] != \
                                self.is_online:
                            self.change_volume_state()
                        # Ensure re-naming is the last change made.
                        if rename_volume:
                            self.rename_volume()

                elif self.state == 'absent':
                    self.delete_volume()

        self.module.exit_json(changed=changed)


def main():
    v = NetAppCDOTVolume()
    v.apply()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm using the below yaml code with Ansible which is using the Python module above.

```
# cat storage.yml
- name: Sample Playbook
  hosts: test-cls-mgt
  connection: local
  vars:
   netapp_hostname: test-cls-mgt
   netapp_username: admin
   netapp_password: admin123
  tasks:
  - na_cdot_volume:
     state: present
     name: ansibleVolume
     infinite: False
     aggregate_name: aggr1
     size: 20
     size_unit: mb
     vserver: vs0
     hostname: "{{ netapp_hostname }}"
     username: "{{ netapp_username }}"
     password: "{{ netapp_password }}"
```

When I run it, I get an error:

```
# ansible-playbook storage.yml

PLAY [Sample Playbook] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [test-cls-mgt]

TASK [Volume Manager] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test-cls-mgt]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "the python NetApp-Lib module is required"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/project/kk.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
test-cls-mgt            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to try to install netapp-lib Python package on your Ansible control host.

For example with this command: `pip install netapp-lib`.

Comment: Konstantin ..  thx for your revert , this i checked its already installed.
Its a kind of fake alert.

`# pip install netapp-lib
Requirement already satisfied: netapp-lib in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from netapp-lib)
`

Comment: looks like something  missing `HAS_NETAPP_LIB = netapp_utils.has_netapp_lib()` on the main python code which i given.

Comment: What Ansible version do you use?

Comment: It's `ansible 2.3.1.0`

Comment: Should work. Check `-vvv` playbook run to ensure that task is executed with `CONNECTION LOCAL` and check your host environment to make sure that Ansible uses same Python as netapp-lib is available for.

Comment: No, its not working . It connects to the Netapp Host but anable to create the volume.

`fatal: [test-cls-mgt]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "the python NetApp-Lib module is required"}`
How we can check which python `netaplib` using.

Comment: Konstantin , thnx for the idea sharing .. It was some other support library issue of python which i installed that's was for logging with Netapp lib which fixed the issue!